Can I set up IPsec tunnels between three branches?
I want to set up IPsec tunnels to connect three branches. In total, you should get three connections:

HQ-BR
BR-DC
DC-HQ

I wanted to do this on the Linux operating system using strongswan tools, but I ran into a problem. If you try to raise more than one connection to one physical interface, the tunnels fall.
Perhaps someone knows how to set up a similar scheme using Strangswan. I attached the diagram to the post, the ip addresses and networks are arbitrary, here only the concept of what I want to achieve is expressed. The scheme of the enterprise

What exactly is the problem? What's that connection vs. interface issue you mention? And how do the tunnels fail?
